# BeautifulSoup 4, Finding text without identifiers

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am helping a non-profit to scrape their eBay store listings.
So far I have this code working properly:

```
    testlink = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pal-Zileri-Mens-Brown-Solid-Loro-Piana-Blazer-44R-2-975/224099569981?hash=item342d60113d:g:DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF'

r = requests.get(testlink, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1', class_='it-ttl').text.strip("Details, about")
price = soup.find('span', class_='notranslate').text.strip("US, $")
ebayID = soup.find('div', class_='u-flL iti-act-num itm-num-txt').text
color = soup.find('h2', itemprop='color').text
brand = soup.find('h2', itemprop='brand').text
```

**However, I am not being able to extract the following info from the image bellow:**

```
44
tree button
wool blend
ventless
solid
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABtbv.png)

also it would be awesome to scrape the information from the image bellow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsfkY.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the item number and attributes, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pal-Zileri-Mens-Brown-Solid-Loro-Piana-Blazer-44R-2-975/224099569981?hash=item342d60113d:g:DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# extract the attributes:
for label, value in zip(soup.select('td.attrLabels'), soup.select('td.attrLabels + td')):
    label = label.get_text(strip=True)
    value = value.get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(label, value))
  
# extract the item number:
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.iframe['src']).content, 'html.parser')
number = soup.find(text=lambda t: t.strip().startswith('Item no.')).find_next('div').get_text(strip=True)
print('NUMBER:', number)
```

Prints:

```
Condition:                     Pre-owned:An item that has been used or worn previously. See the seller’s listing for full details anddescription of any imperfections.See all condition definitions- opens in a new window or tab...Read moreabout the condition
Size:                          44
Type:                          Blazer
Jacket/Coat Length:            Regular
Color:                         Brown
Department:                    Men
Brand:                         Pal Zileri
Chest Size:                    44
Jacket Front Button Style:     Three-Button
Material:                      Wool Blend
Jacket Vent Style:             Ventless
Pattern:                       Solid
Size Type:                     Regular
Fit:                           Athletic
NUMBER: LXW349-JULW3
```

---

EDIT:

To save the labes/values in dictionary and to csv, you can use this example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pal-Zileri-Mens-Brown-Solid-Loro-Piana-Blazer-44R-2-975/224099569981?hash=item342d60113d:g:DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = {}

# extract the attributes:
for label, value in zip(soup.select('td.attrLabels'), soup.select('td.attrLabels + td')):
    label = label.get_text(strip=True)
    label = label.rstrip(':').lower()
    value = value.get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(label, value))
    data[label] = value

# extract the item number:
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.iframe['src']).content, 'html.parser')
number = soup.find(text=lambda t: t.strip().startswith('Item no.')).find_next('div').get_text(strip=True)
print('NUMBER:', number)
data['item number'] = number

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT 2: To include an image link:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pal-Zileri-Mens-Brown-Solid-Loro-Piana-Blazer-44R-2-975/224099569981?hash=item342d60113d:g:DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
# https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF/s-l1600.jpg
data = {}

# extract the attributes:
for label, value in zip(soup.select('td.attrLabels'), soup.select('td.attrLabels + td')):
    label = label.get_text(strip=True)
    label = label.rstrip(':').lower()
    value = value.get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(label, value))
    data[label] = value

# extract the image
image = soup.select_one('[itemprop="image"]')['src'].replace('l300', 'l1600')
data['image'] = image

# extract the item number:
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.iframe['src']).content, 'html.parser')
number = soup.find(text=lambda t: t.strip().startswith('Item no.')).find_next('div').get_text(strip=True)
print('NUMBER:', number)
data['item number'] = number

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hey, Andrej.
First, thank you for your help. it seems that the tutorial I have is using 'lxml' instead of 'html.parser' and I think that was why I was getting none values.

Is there a way to store the values in variables that correspond to the labels instead of printing them?

My goal is ultimately to set the labels as keys and the values as values on a dictionary and export everything into a csv file.

Comment: You rock!!!!
If I am not abusing your time, I still didn't figure out how to take the image link.

<img id="viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr" alt="" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/DWAAAOSwNZFfEHjF/s-l1600.jpg" clk="" style="width: 386.25px; height: 515px;">

I would like to have this one also as one of the columns

Comment: @jonathan You can do for example `image = soup.select_one('[itemprop="image"]')['src']` If you want high resolution image then `image = soup.select_one('[itemprop="image"]')['src'].replace('l300', 'l1600')`. Then `data['image'] = image`

Comment: I parsed your code right bellow 
data['item number'] = number
getting this error
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @jonathan Did you copy my script as is? It seems your variable `data` is `None`. It should be a dictionary.

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you. I hope one day I am that good. You are awesome.